# iOS - Opening Search App programmatically

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, corespotlight

I would like to know how it is possible to search something on iOS devices programmatically (Spotlight?) using Universal links or direct methods (native code) to open the search app like on Android.

In my Android app I have

```
String string = query;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox");
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox", "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.SearchActivity");
intent.putExtra("query", string);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

This code performs a search that sometimes allows assistant-like results with the possibility to open relevant apps or the web browser and so on.

I think also iOS have this feature. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your app searchable with Siri, but you cannot, in code, trigger a Siri search.

Comment: @matt Yes I know that Siri cannot be triggered programmatically (at least at present time, and the same is on Android for the Assistant) but my question is about Spotlight search or a similar search, no conversation or artificial intelligence involved, just sending a string as a search query.